# Installed Magento 2, tried to go to the Magento Frontend/Admin in Chrome, but only get "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: magento2, installation, frontend-error

I have been trying to fix this since yesterday without any seeming success or even progress, so I hope someone out there can figure it out and help me.

I have installed Magento 2 using the Ubuntu console, on a pc running windows 10.

> I followed this guide
>   (https://websiteforstudents.com/install-magento-2-using-composer-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-with-apache2-mariadb-and-php-7-1-support/)
>   but at step 8 (the last step) I restarted apache2 and found that the
>   Magento Frontend and Admin weren't accessible for some reason.
>
> I tried entering both `localhost/magento2` and `jjsmykker.dk` into the
>   Chrome address bar, `magento2` being the `ServerName` and
>   `http://jjsmykker.dk/` being the `ServerAlias` in the `magento2.conf`,
>   but all attempts ended in the same error being shown in Chrome (as
>   well as the other browsers I've tried it in).

Below I've included an image of the error Chrome is throwing at me, as well as an image of the `magento2.conf` file.

I'm a beginner at both Magento and at using the Ubuntu Console, so I hope you'll bear with me, and that someone here can help me out and get me moving forward after being stuck with this for far too long!

[image: Chrome error page]

[image: magento2.conf file]

> EDIT 1:
>
> I ran these commands as it was suggested in an answer here. It didn't
>   change the error message on Chrome, but I've added this image to show
>   an apache2 warning that according to my research shouldn't impact this
>   situation, but as I'm new at this I've included it just in case I'm
>   wrong. [image: Suggestion 1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try to run below commands

```
sudo a2ensite magento2.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

And also add your URL in `/etc/hosts`

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

> 127.0.0.1 jjsmykker.dk

If on windows remember to change the hosts file manually in windows too! ([link](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/))

**Update :**

To create virtual host follow below given steps one by one

> sudo mkdir -p /var/www/magento2
>
> sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/magento2
>
> sudo nano /var/www/magento2/index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to magento2!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Success! The magento2 virtual host is working!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

> sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/magento2.conf
>
> sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/magento2.conf

```
ServerName magento2
ServerAlias magento2

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/magento2

<Directory /var/www/magento2>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

> sudo a2ensite magento2.conf
>
> sudo service apache2 reload

Follow this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I've done as instructed now, without success, unfortunately.
I've added an extra image to the bottom of my post do show the commands I ran, since Apache2 does give me a warning when I restart or start it, but I've googled the warning and it shouldn't hinder me in what I'm doing if I understood it correctly.

Comment: Please try to remove http from server alias and only use this "jjsmykker.dk"

Comment: No success, it still gives the same error in Chrome and after loading it still changes the address bar to `jjsmykker/`

Comment: Please add index.html file and try to run that with browser and check if that is working or not so we can check other things.

Comment: I already have the `Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page` in `/var/www/html/index.html`, and when I go to `localhost` in Chrome, the `Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page` shows up as it's supposed to.

Comment: You mean when you run this in browser you got o/p, Right ? http://jjsmykker.dk/index.html

Comment: Ohh, no, I simply typed `localhost` in the browsers address bar.
`jjsmykker.dk/index.html` gives the same error currently.
But I haven't added another `index.html` file yet, where am I supposed to create the new `index.html` file?

Comment: Means your virtual host is not setup yet. Please follow link which I have added in my answer

Comment: Ohh, okay. It should be up and running according to the guide I followed, but I will use the guide in your link and see if I can get it working properly then :)

Comment: I've run through the guide you linked now, and every step of the guide succeded without any issues, but unfortunately, it hasn't changed anything in Chrome. The same error shows up in the browser as in the above image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102029/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-p-g).

Comment: Please click on above link, so we can discuss there

Answer (score 0):

G, It can be issue of htaccess or folder permission, try to rename .htaccess file on root and see if it working for you?

Comment: I'm not certain I have a `.htaccess` file currently? If I understand correctly it is supposed to be located in the root, right? If so I don't currently have one.